# Gradle dependency between subprojects

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to figure out the proper way to declare a project dependency in gradle, i have this two subprojects:

A java app

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {main {java {srcDirs = ['./']}}}
dependencies{compile project(':p2')}

jar {manifest.attributes(
        'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { it.name }.join(''),
        'Main-Class': 'Main'
    )
}
```

and a java library:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

sourceSets {main {java {srcDirs = ['./']}}
}

jar {
   manifest.attributes(
    'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { it.name }.join(' ')
)
}
```

The root project is empty and the settings just include the subprojects.

The `dependencies` in the p1 project only tells that p2 must be built before p1, but what about configuring p2 as a lib for p1? Right now if a run p1 i got:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: StaticClass`

Gradle build is fine:

```
C:\...>gradle build
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 4 up-to-date
```

I have to copy and paste p2.jar to the p1.jar directory for it to run properly, how can i get gradle to do it for me?

Comment: This looks like it should work to me. What does your grradle build console look like?

Comment: I edited the post with the gradle output.
I tested now, if i put this line in the jar task: `from configurations.compile.collect { zipTree it }` i can get the p2 class files to go inside my jar, but it looks like wrong, doesn't the java plugin have a configuration where i set the dependency and it will put the right files in the final jar?

Comment: Reading the docs from here: `https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations` i tested the following dependencies: `runtimeOnly`, `compile`, `implementation`, none of them does the job.

Comment: Ah - are you trying to include the classes from p2 _inside_ the p1 jar? The gradle dependency system doesn't do that - it adds the p2 jar to the classpath of p1, and also sets it as a module dependency if you publish it as a Maven or Ivy module.

Comment: I read your answer, i think i'm uderstanding now, but where does gradle set the classpath for p2 in p1? i can't run p1 properly and the manifest file is empty, to get things to work i have to manually copy p2.jar to the same folder of p1.jar and write: `'Class-Path': 'p2.jar'`.

Comment: Which classpath? Compile time or runtime? You say that you're trying to "run" p1, but you're not using the Application Plugin, which manages the runtime classpath for you. So how are you running p1? And how do you _want_ to package and run p1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to pack the classes from `p2` into the `p1` jar, try adding this to p1's `build.gradle`:

```
jar {
    from project(':p2:').sourceSets.main.output
}
```

This is a bit unusual, though. Normally, if you've set up a separate library project, you pack it in a separate jar and add it to the classpath of dependent projects, so it's reusable.

Setting the Class-Path on the jar's manifest won't work the way you've written it. The manifest attribute interprets each entry as a *file path* relative to the working dir of the JVM, but you're just giving it the *name* of each jar, and Gradle doesn't do any copying or moving of files when setting up configuration classpaths. It's generally not a good idea to rely on the manifest to set the classpath, as it will only work if your jars are arranged on the filesystem exactly as as the manifest expects it. If this is really what you want, then you need to set up an 'installation' directory containing all the required jars arranged as expected. The [Gradle Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) can probably help you to achieve this, or something equivalent, but I've never used it.

Comment: Hmm, i understand now, this is the job of another plugin, i finally made it, i used the `java-library` for my library wich have transitive dependencies and used the `application` plugin for my application, the application plugin is really what i needed. Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact needs, you should have a look at the [`java-library-distribution` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_distribution_plugin.html) or the [`application` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).

- The first one will package a jar and its dependencies in an archive.
- The second one will do the same and allow you to configure the main jar to be executable.